# COMANDO DE INSERÇÃO JUNTAMENTE COM O FOMRULÁRIO PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, inserir

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se existe um meio de colocar os comandos de sql pra inserção no mesmo formulário que os inputs. Obrihado!

FORMULÁRIO DE INSERÇÃO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cadastro de Usuário</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id='container'>
  <div class='signup'>
     <form action="cadastrar1.php" method="POST">
       <input name="nome" type='text' placeholder='Nome:' required=".$this->fields["nome"]."/>
       <input name="sobrenome" type='text' placeholder='Sobrenome:'required=".$this->fields["sobrenome"].  />
       <input name="rm" type='text' placeholder='RM:' required=".$this->fields["rm"]."/>
       <input name="curso" type='text' placeholder='Curso:' required=".$this->fields["rm"]."/>
       <input name="data_nasc" type='date' placeholder='Data de Nacimento:' required=".$this->fields["rm"]."/">
       <input name="email" type='text' placeholder='Email:' required=".$this->fields["rm"]."/>
       <input name="senha" type='password' placeholder='Senha:' required=".$this->fields["rm"]."/>
       <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>

     </form>
  </div>
  <div class='whysign'>
    <h1>Teste de Cadastro de Dados :3</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p> 

    </p>
  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

CADASTRAR.PHP

```
 if(!$conect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cadastros')) 
    die ('erro ao conectar');

#Recolhendo os dados do formulário
    $nome=$_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome=$_POST['sobrenome'];
    $data=$_POST['data_nasc'];
    $rm=$_POST['rm'];
    $curso=$_POST['curso'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $senha=$_POST['senha'];

# Verificando apenas um campo, no caso dado1.
    $sql = $conect->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            echo "Este usuário já existe";
        exit(); 
    } 
        else {

        if(!$conect->query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, data_nasc, rm, curso, email, senha) 
            VALUES('$nome','$sobrenome','$data','$rm','$curso','$email','$senha')")) 
        die ('Os dados não foram inseridos');
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro Concluído!');</script>";
        header('Location: index.html');
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo meu amigo, pode ser mais específico, o que realmente deseja fazer?

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível. Para isso você precisa utilizar o método `isset`.

```php
if (isset($_POST['cadastro']))
{
    // Aqui vai o código do cadastrar.php
}
```

Para este código funcionar, você precisa adicionar uma propriedade na sua declaração do formulário no HTML, ficaria assim:

```html
<form action="cadastrar1.php" name="cadastro" method="POST">
```

Apesar deste código funcionar, não é uma boa prática deixar a lógica do programa no mesmo arquivo em que você exibe o HTML, pois isso reduz a manutenibilidade do código, além de ser uma má prática de programação.

Fazendo uma análise do seu código, eu gostaria de sugerir duas coisas importantes para você aprender e aplicar nos seus projetos:

#### 1. Utilizar MVC ou algum outro padrão de separação de camadas

Para projetos mais complexos ou soluções que tenham alta demanada MVC não é o mais adequado, mas por ser um conceito bem fácil de aprender e de aplicar, é o que eu recomendo para quem está iniciando. No início você pode pensar que é bem mais rápido fazer tudo em um arquivo só, mas conforme o tempo passa e o projeto vai aumentando, você percebe que qualquer alteração que você (ou outra pessoa) faça vai exigir que várias partes do código sejam alteradas. É aí que a separação de camadas entra em cena. Não vou me alongar muito nesse assunto, mas vou deixar um link do Tableless abaixo que explica com mais detalhes o que é e quais os benefícios.

https://tableless.com.br/mvc-afinal-e-o-que/

#### 2. Usar ferramentas que evitem SQL Injection

Caso não saiba o que é, SQL Injection é um método de ataque que pessoas usam entradas de formulário que não são validadas antes de serem executadas no banco de dados. Vou tentar explicar de forma simples:

- Aqui está o código que vai ser executado no SQL segundo está no cadastra.php

```sql
INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, data_nasc, rm, curso, email, senha) 
            VALUES('$nome','$sobrenome','$data','$rm','$curso','$email','$senha')
```

- Agora, vamos supor que eu coloque na senha o valor `'); DROP TABLE usuarios; --`
- Quando eu inserir esse formulário, o servidor irá executar:

```sql
INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, sobrenome, data_nasc, rm, curso, email, senha) 
VALUES('nome qualquer','sobrenome qualquer','data qualquer','rm qualquer','curso qualquer',
'email qualquer',''); DROP TABLE usuarios; --')
```

Percebeu que isso não só formou um comando SQL válido como vai deletar sua tabela de usuários inteira? Ataques como esses são comuns e são chamados de SQL Injection.

Você pode saber mais sobre SQL Injection nesse link da OWASP (em inglês): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Para evitar SQL Injection com PHP, uma das maneiras é executar as chamadas usando Prepared Statements.

Você pode conferir o link da documentação oficial aqui (em inglês): https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php